# How to create accordion in Drupal for grouped elements of a view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have some elements in my View (realized with the View module). Let's say a list of Events. Events are grouped in the View by year (with the View option grouping by 'field_year'). Let's say we have events related to 2014, 2013 and 2012. I want the events about the current year to be showed plain and the other hid, having a sort of dropdown button allowing to show or hide the events related to a certain Year.
Something like:

```
2014
- Event 1
- Event 2
2013 ->
2012 ->
```

It is possible using Views?

EDIT: maybe "dropdown" is not the right term... What i mean is kind of a div showing and hiding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [views accordion module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion) can solve your problem. Check the grouping options and don't forget to select the checkbox "Use the group header as the Accordion header " to avoid duplicate headers.